# Where to save ~500 image files for MERN app

Tags: image, reactjs

I am building a sports web app, and for the application I need thumbnail images for each NBA basketball player. I have written a script that grabs image paths (links like this - http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/nba/players/full/3414.png&w=350&h=254), so I have access to all of the images, but I am not sure what React best-practices are with regards to where to save these types of images. I think my options are:

1. Save the image files for each player in the app directory (where other images are saved, i think the assets folder of my app), and import them into the app.
2. Don't save the image files, but rather create a table in my database with player IDs and image paths, and have my app use these paths to grab the already hosted images.
3. Both A and B essentially. First save the image files, and then re-host the image files myself, and link to these newly hosted images.

Do those 3 choices make sense? i feel like (3) is the best option but also requires the most work. (2) seems like the easiest but least reliable, since I cannot trust that the already-hosted image urls will always work, and (1) just doesn't seem like the best approach, since it would require hundreds of import statements in my app to get all of the images.

Not a coding question, but I think this has a broad applicability and am hoping the post can stay up. Any help or thoughts are appreciated on this!

Edit: for reference, here's something along the lines of what my table looks like:

```
> player.image.df
      [,1]                [,2]                                                                                       
 [1,] "alex-abrines"      "http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/nba/players/full/2995702.png&w=350&h=254"
 [2,] "quincy-acy"        "http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/nba/players/full/6576.png&w=350&h=254"   
 [3,] "steven-adams"      "http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/nba/players/full/2991235.png&w=350&h=254"
 [4,] "bam-adebayo"       "http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/nba/players/full/4066261.png&w=350&h=254"
 [5,] "arron-afflalo"     "http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/nba/players/full/3187.png&w=350&h=254"   
 [6,] "alexis-ajinca"     "http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/nba/players/full/3410.png&w=350&h=254"   
 [7,] "cole-aldrich"      "http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/nba/players/full/4267.png&w=350&h=254"   
 [8,] "lamarcus-aldridge" "http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/nba/players/full/2983.png&w=350&h=254"   
 [9,] "jarrett-allen"     "http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/nba/players/full/4066328.png&w=350&h=254"
[10,] "kadeem-allen"      "http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/nba/players/full/3134880.png&w=350&h=254"
```

These aren't my links, and I have no way to know if ESPN ever changes these links, which is why I think (3) is the best approach here. But I'm not sure how to host my own images quickly and easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the third option, its definitely the most reliable way to make sure that those image are available and use it as you want.

You don't have to make an import for each image, once you have all your image path  in your database you can use require() function to load it dynamically.

You just have to make a script to download all the images on the CDN and save its new path into your database.

-Edit-

I'm considering that your server and your bandwitdh, are strong enough to manage the extra work generated by self hosted images.

Comment: what's the best / easiest / cheapest way to host 500 images quickly

Comment: thank you for your thoughts. I host my app on heroku.

Comment: unfortunately cheapest and easiest don't really work together. The verry best would be to have your own CDN and it's also the easiest, but it's not really cheap. The cheapest  is to make your own server with a linux distrib and host your app with all the images on it.

Comment: heroku as a CDN addon, it starts at  25$/ month for 100gb and/or 10M request.  https://elements.heroku.com/addons/fastly